# What does `:load` do and what does it not do in Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following code:

```
abstract class AExp {
  def eval : Int = this match {
    case Num(n) => n
    case Add(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
  }
}

case class Num(n : Int) extends AExp
case class Add(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp

case class Prd(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp {
  override def eval : Int = e1.eval * e2.eval
}
```

It works fine under Scala 2.8 [here](http://www.simplyscala.com/) but does not work under 2.10 when I load it into the REPL.  I get tons of errors:

```
scala> :l aexp.scala
Loading aexp.scala...
<console>:9: error: not found: value Num
           case Num(n) => n
                ^
<console>:9: error: not found: value n
           case Num(n) => n
                          ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value Add
           case Add(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
                ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value e1
           case Add(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
                               ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Num(n : Int) extends AExp
                                       ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Add(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp
                                                    ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Add(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp
                           ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Add(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp
                                      ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Prd(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp {
                                                    ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Prd(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp {
                           ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type AExp
       case class Prd(e1 : AExp, e2 : AExp) extends AExp {
                                      ^
```

But the same code works fine in `:paste` mode under the 2.10 REPL.  What is going on here?  What does `:load` do and what does it not do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `:help` says,

> :load 
>   load and interpret a Scala file

it loads file and **interprets** it **line-by-line**, just like it would interpret individual lines that you feed to REPL, whereas :paste interpret whole chunk of code as an atomical unit.

The error, as you can predict is that repl sees

```
abstract class AExp {
  def eval : Int = this match {
    case Num(n) => n
    case Add(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
  }
}
```

But know nothing about Num and Add types -- they aren't defined yet. The trick to make :load work the way you wanted to is to wrap all your code in some super object, e.g.:

```
object InterpretAsUnit {
  // all your code goes there
}
```

P.S. 
funny fact, is that `scala -i <your path>` nearly identical to `scala` and then `:load <your path>`

Comment: Oh My.  Shouldn't this be documented clearly in the `:help`?  Thanks a lot.  Saved my nightmare.

Comment: @plmday I can't tell if this answer says: in 2.11, :paste file does what you want.  The :help says, `:paste [-raw] [path]     enter paste mode or paste a file`.

Comment: @som-snytt yep, [among other changes there is enhanced :paste mode](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/)